# Is there a way to emulate two finger swipe on Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have enabled "Emulate touch events" and can perform normal swipe. 
Is there a way to emulate 2 finger swipe? And other such gestures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/#toc-touchdev (the MULTI-TOUCH EVENTS subsection) - it contains some treatment of the subject.